# How to convert nvarchar to date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to retrieve data from database between two dates but its show me the error converting data type nvarchar to date.
Here is my code:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");            
    }
```

Comment: can you tell the date format that is saved in the database?

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel in database format is `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it will be better if you change the datatype of the column of your database table from nvarchar to datetime, because in that case you can store .net datetime directly to the column of the table and retrieve it as well to your datetime variable. Or you can change your column to varchar because it consumes more memory space then nvarchar and then you can store your datetime value as string and when you retrieve you can convert to your desired format net. You can also Use DateTime.Parse() or ParseExact() to create a datetime Object from the date text and time.

```
string iDate = "2005-05-05";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(iDate);
MsgBox(oDate.Day & " " & oDate.Month & "  " & oDate.Year)

string iString = "2005-05-05 22:12 PM";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
MessageBox.Show(oDate.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, `Text` properties of `TextBox1` and `TextBox1` are used to create an SQL query with a datetime condition. If so, use the following format specifier when converting to string: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`